# Estrutura de repetição para substituir o valor de um array para outro

Tags: angular, typescript

Tenho o array `this.produtoAlvoAlterar.variacao.preco_variacao`

Preciso substituir o preco_variacao desse array pelo valor contido no array `this.anuncioAlterar.variations.specifications.preco`

Tentei fazer uma estrutura de repetição para passar esses valores de um array pra outro, ficou assim:

```
  for(let i=0;i<this.produtoAlvoAlterar.variacao.length;i++){
    for(let j=0;j<this.anuncioAlterar.variations.length;j++){
      for(let k=0;k<this.anuncioAlterar.variations[j].specifications.length;k++){
        if(this.anuncioAlterar.variations[j].specifications[k].key == "Preço"){
          this.produtoAlvoAlterar.variacao[i].preco_variacao = this.anuncioAlterar.variations[j].specifications[k].value;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Na primeira posição do array o valor de  `this.produtoAlvoAlterar.variacao.preco_variacao` deveria ser setado o valor "222,22" e na segunda posição para "333,33" porém ambas posições estão tendo o valor "333,33", que é o valor do segundo key do array `this.anuncioAlterar.variations.specifications`

@Edit:

[image: Array this.produtoAlvoAlterar.variacao.preco_variacao]

[image: Array this.anuncioAlterar.variations.specifications]

Comment: Você pode editar sua pergunta e colocar os arrays? assim fica mais fácil para ajudar...

Comment: Essa sua estrutura de dados está confusa. Ter 3 fors um dentro do outro não é nada escalavél.

Comment: Editei o post com as informações dos arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta utilizar esse código. No código ele percorre todo `this.produtoAlvoAlterar.variacao` e `this.anuncioAlterar.variations`, ele pega o `Preço` de cada `anuncioAlterar` e settar no `produtoAlvoAlterar`.

```
this.produtoAlvoAlterar.variacao.forEach(variacao => {
      this.anuncioAlterar.variations.forEach(anuncioVariacao => {
        let novoPreco = anuncioVariacao.specifications.filter(
            chaveValor => {
              return chaveValor.key === 'Preço';
          });

        variacao.preco_variacao = novoPreco;
      })
    });
```